# How to bind kubernetes resource to helm release

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

If I run `kubectl apply -f <some statefulset>.yaml` separately, is there a way to bind the stateful set to a previous helm release? (eg by specifying some tags in the yaml file)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know - you cannot do it.

Yes, you can always [create resources via templates](https://docs.helm.sh/chart_template_guide/) before installing the Helm chart.

However, I have never seen a solution for your question.